# Chrome Performance: Long GPU Blocks in Timeline

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-chrome, gpu

I am developing a web application (JS/CSS/AngularJS) which is going to run on a touchscreen client.
As the application grows I run into a performance problem: I mentioned that the applicaion is not running with 60fps but 30 or something. Therefore I used the chrome built-in timeline tool to profile what's going on under the hood.
Okay - there are many long frames which limit the fps to ~30. The reason are the large GPU blocks (green) you can see in the screenshots).

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]
It seems that the GPU is taking much time to... render? calculate? ...?
Unfortunally I don't have any further information what the GPU does in this time. There are some CSS effects and transforms but nothing really spectacular.
It's running on a Intel HD Graphics 530 (onboard) but I think is should even perform with 60fps on this one.

I'd like to know if there is any way to get further information what is slowing down the GPU that much and/or if there are any common CSS tricks to speed up my page. Or is there anything I can tweak at the GPU itself?

Thanks!